# Gradle export produces empty jar

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, jar

My project has a parent project and a couple included projects. Along those, one called FileEncrypter and one called ListenerPattern.
I've got the following script in a parent project:

```
subprojects{
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'maven'
    apply plugin: 'java'

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }

    dependencies { 

      compile fileTree(dir: 'build', include: '*.jar')
      testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
      testCompile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.6.1'
    }

    task export(type: Jar) << {
        manifest {
            attributes 'Implementation-Title': 'Exported jar',  
                'Implementation-Version': version
        }
        sourceCompatibility = 1.7
        baseName = "$it.project.name"
        println baseName
        println sourceSets.main.java
        from { sourceSets.main.java }
        with jar
    }
}
```

In both projects I delete the build directory. Next, I run `gradle build`, on them each individually, not the parent project. In both projects the build folder reappears, containing a `libs` folder, containing a jar file. The jar-files have the folders `META-INF` and `nl`, as expected. (The folder nl has the rest of that package's content.)

Now on both I run `gradle export`. I look at the jar-files again, and they ONLY have the `META-INF` file. So my question is, what in the world could be going wrong here? This went fine until not too long ago.

Comment: Are you modifying source sets anywhere?

Comment: Nope. At least 15 characters in a comment....

Comment: Can you try removing `<<` in the task definition?